# How to hide the text and checkbox when checked to remove in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, checkbox

How to hide the checkbox with the text getting removed in the below picture :

Screen 1 :

When the page is loaded the screen would look like below :

[image]

Screen 2 :

When the checkbox is checked ,the text disappears but checkbox remains there.

[image]

Javascript Code:

```
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.todos = [
    {text:'learn angular', done:true},
    {text:'build an angular app', done:false}];

  $scope.addTodo = function() {
    $scope.todos.push({text:$scope.todoText, done:false});
    $scope.todoText = '';
  };

  $scope.remaining = function() {
    var count = 0;
    angular.forEach($scope.todos, function(todo) {
      count += todo.done ? 0 : 1;
    });
    return count;
  };

  $scope.archive = function() {
    var oldTodos = $scope.todos;
    $scope.todos = [];
    angular.forEach(oldTodos, function(todo) {
      if (!todo.done) $scope.todos.push(todo);
    });
  };
}
```

[FIDDLE LINK HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/15742/)

Comment: You might want to consider hiding the elements using [ng-hide](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide), instead of adding a class and hiding the element with a CSS style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this](http://jsfiddle.net/vLb7cu4h/1/) fiddle

```
 <li ng-repeat="todo in todos" class="done-{{todo.done}}">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="todo.done">
    <span >{{todo.text}}</span>
  </li>
```

You had to move the class to the whole list element to hide it, not only the text

Answer (score 0):

put the `class="done-{{todo.done}}"`

also on the checkbox

> `<input class="done-{{todo.done}}" type="checkbox" ng-model="todo.done">`